# Why does ES6 copy class variables inside methods?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reference, pass-by-reference, variable-assignment

I have a JavaScript/ES6 `class` with a member that is an array called `x`, initialized to `[1,2,3,4]`.

When I declare a new variable in a method, called `y`, and assign `x` to it, and then change the values in `x`, `y` remains unchanged, indicating that `y` is a copy of `x`.

If I declare and assign `y` to a variable called `z` in the same method, modifying `z` changes `y`, but doesn't change `x`.

This would indicate that declaring a class level array (object?) and then assigning it to a variable inside a method copies the object. This differs significantly from languages like C#.

Why is it implemented this way in JavaScript/ES6?

```js
class Alpha {
  constructor() {
    this.x = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  }

  DoSomething() {

    console.log('x is ' + this.x); // x is 1,2,3,4

    let y = this.x;
    this.x = [99, 99, 99, 99];

    console.log('x is ' + this.x); // x is 99,99,99,99
    console.log('y is ' + y); // y is 1,2,3,4 (?)

    let z = y;
    z[1] = 888;

    console.log('x is ' + this.x); // x is 99,99,99,99
    console.log('y is ' + y); // y is 1,888,3,4
    console.log('z is ' + z); // z is 1,888,3,4

  }
}

let thing = new Alpha();
thing.DoSomething()
```

Comment: You're "modifying" in two different ways.  `x` and `y` are pointing to two different values in memory.

Comment: This would have worked out exactly the same in C#.

Comment: **you have an error in your code** witch is targeted in strict mode  ` ( " use strict" ) : SyntaxError: redeclaration of this.x `    and you better must read my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let y = this.x;
this.x = [99, 99, 99, 99];
```

y now points to [1,2,3,4]....this.x now points to a **new array** [99,99,99,99];

**EDIT**

For the record, this has nothing to do with ES6

**EDIT #2**

y now points to a location in memory that contains the array [1,2,3,4] and this.x now points to a different location in memory that contains an array [99,99,99,99];

At the heart of this question is the understanding of memory allocation.

Answer (score 2):

This is how the memory is storing the values and how the variables are pointing to different values in memory.

```
 Statement                 Value of x              Value of y
+------------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
|  let x = [1, 2, 3, 4]; |  [1, 2, 3, 4]       |                   |
|  let y = x;            |  [1, 2, 3, 4]       |   [1, 2, 3, 4]    |
|  x = [99, 99, 99, 99]; |  [99, 99, 99, 99]   |   [1, 2, 3, 4]    |
+------------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
```

Basically, the two variables contain/point to different values, so modifications in one variable won't' affect the other.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with class or class methods, and that has always existed in javascript.
    
    `let tab_origin = [ "aa", "bb",  "cc" ]; 
    let same_tab = tab_origin;`

this make `tab_origin` and `same_tab` to point on the same address of the array.
in other word you have only one array and two different variables to access it.
    
    `same_tab[0] = "zz";
    console.log( tab_origin[0] ); // => "zz"`

be careful of this for functions:
    
    `function myfunction(inTab)
    {
      inTab[1] = "ff"
    }

    myfunction(tab_origin);
    console.log( tab_origin[1] ); // => "ff" !!`

so, if you want a copy of your array you have to do :
    
    `let other_tab = Object.assign( [], tab_origin );` 

as its name suggests this method allows to assign a new object
    
    `other_tab[2] = "xy";
    console.log( tab_origin[2] ); // => "cc" - unchanged :)
    console.log( other_tab[2] );  // => "xy"`

```js
let tab_origin = [ "aa", "bb",  "cc" ];

let same_tab = tab_origin; 

same_tab[0] = "zz";
console.log( 'tab_origin[0]', tab_origin[0] ); // => "zz"

function myfunction(inTab)
{ 
  inTab[1] = "ff";
}  

myfunction(tab_origin);
console.log( 'tab_origin[1]', tab_origin[1] ); // => "ff"

let other_tab = Object.assign( [], tab_origin ); 


other_tab[2] = "xy";
console.log( 'tab_origin[2]', tab_origin[2] ); // => "cc"
console.log( 'other_tab[0]',  other_tab[2] );  // => "xy"
```